# Consumer-driven Contract Testing

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, unit-tests, api-testing, api

I've just come across the term consumer-driven contract testing and, working as a QA, was wondering a few things:

1. What does this actually mean in laymans terms?
2. Who would generally execute this type of testing (e.g. dev or QA)?
3. What tools could be used for testing this?
4. Could a specific programming language be used to test this (e.g. a framework written in C#)?

Comment: https://reflectoring.io/7-reasons-for-consumer-driven-contracts/